# Executing python3 file with a cron job.

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, ubuntu

I have a python3 script located in /home/valence/ that gets the weather forecast for the current day (max and min temperature values in Celsius) from Yahoo! weather API. The file looks exactly like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from urllib import request
import json
url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D349859%20and%20u='c'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback="
response=request.urlopen(url)
str_response = response.readall().decode('utf-8')
dic = json.loads(str_response)
dic["query"]["results"]["channel"]["location"]["region"]="R.M."
low=dic["query"]["results"]["channel"]["item"]["forecast"][0]["low"]
high=dic["query"]["results"]["channel"]["item"]["forecast"][0]["high"]
forecast=open("forecast.txt", "w+")
forecast.write("Minima: "+str(low)+" Maxima: "+str(high))
forecast.close()
```

It works fine when I execute it. It creates or overwrites the file forecast.txt with the right values, but when I try to use cron to execute with the following cron job:

```
* * * * * /home/valence/Get_forecast.py
```

no file forecast.txt is created or modified.

So I need to know what I am doing wrong and how to make this work as intended. The cron job is not meant to be executed every minute (because forecast for a day remains the same throughout the day), but for now I have it that way so I can see changes without having to wait much.

Note: I am new to linux (I am using Lubuntu)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason why you don't get the file `forecast.txt` in directory `/home/valence` when using crontab job `* * * * * /home/valence/Get_forecast.py` is that the cron don't execute the command in directory `/home/valence` and you specified the file `forecast.txt` in relative path form in your program. So the file is created somewhere else.

To get the expected file output, you can use the following crontab job:

```
* * * * * cd /home/valence && ./Get_forecast.py
```

This explicitly assign the current working directory to be `/home/valence`, and execute the script from there.

What's more, to get the output from stdout and stderr, add redirection is always helpful when something unexpected happens:

```
* * * * * cd /home/valence && ./Get_forecast.py > /tmp/forecast.log 2>&1
```

Note:

The previous two crontab job assumes Get_forecast.py jexecutable and with shebang specified. The `./Get_forecast.py` part can always be replaced with `python3 Get_forecast.py` or `/usr/bin/python3 Get_forecast.py` to be more clear.

Comment: Could someone explain what changes are required to make the cron job run: `* * * * * /home/valence/Get_forecast.py` rather than having to cd dir and execute the script?

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me to run a python3 script is the next:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/gabriel/python/myScript.py
```

Using `which python3` find the path to your python version and then add the path to your file.

Comment: Absolute path fixed my issue

Comment: yes useful, in my case, it is in …miniconda

Answer (score 2):

i think your cronjob is not at all running your program. Way to run a program is like this

```
python script.py
```

so your cronjob must look like this.

```
* * * * * python /home/valence/Get_forecast.py
```

or

```
* * * * * cd /home/valence && python Get_forecast.py
```

you can send all the outputs of a cronjob to a log file like this.

```
* * * * * cd /home/valence && python Get_forecast.py >> output_logs.op
```

Comment: If Get_forecast.py is executable file then there is nothing wrong with "executing" directly /home/valence/Get_forecast.py. As you can see, he specified interpreter at start of the file by #!/sur/bin/python3

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend providing an absolute path to the output file:

```
forecast=open("/tmp/forecast.txt", "w+")
```

Cron gets a little funny with paths / permissions and ownership of scripts that execute.  Let me know if the file gets created under /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this tool](http://crontab-generator.org/) to generate the command and I usually do something like

```
 10 * * * * /home/valence/Get_forecast.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```