# I want my cronjob to run a script every minute but it's not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

First thing I did was:

```
crontab -e
```

Then I added this line:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/user/Desktop/test.py
```

The script is a simple script that should just create a new file every minute (I'm just playing around with crontab at the moment) but nothing happens.
The file is executable and I did that with

`chmod +x test.py`

The path is also correct, I've checked with both realpath and pwd.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: try this `1    *    *    *    *    python /home/user/Desktop/test.py`

Comment: try to put `#!/usr/bin/python` on the first line of your script

Comment: @Faboor Thanks for the answer. I got "#!/usr/bin/env python3" at the moment.

Comment: @Shubham Thanks! Still not working for some reason :/ The script works in the terminal but not with cronjob.

Comment: Some good pointers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527469/executing-python3-file-with-a-cron-job start with adding this to the end `> /tmp/mycron.log 2>&1`

Comment: @brennan Thank you! It works now, all I did was "cd /home/user/Desktop/ && python test.py"

Comment: This is one of common -- canonical almost -- things about `crontab` ... why not write up your solution and post it as an answer (and accept it)?